# lpcxpresso UART and DMA

Tags: lpc

Does anybody have experience with the UART and DMA on the 1769 lpcxpresso board without the baseboard?  I can get it to transmit the FIFO buffer but I am not able to get it to acknowledge any received chars.  If it matters I am using the MCB1700, DMA-UART example code. Is there any place where I can get code examples to get this to work?

I am using the MCB1700 example code which comes with the lpcxpresso code_red. This uses UART0 and UART1 thru a RS-232 cable and 2 DMA channels. but the RS232 connection to connect the 2 ports is on the baseboard but I don't have one. I am just using wires on a breadboard to hook up UART0 TX to UART1 RX and the UART1 TX to the UART0 RX. I am notified that I received the 16 byte FIFO buffer from UART1 but when UART0 transmits to UART1, I am not getting the flag set saying I received the characters on the other DMA channel. I am wondering if something is not being initialized correctly

Comment: I am using the MCB1700 example code which comes with the lpcxpresso code_red. This uses UART0 and UART1 thru a RS-232 cable and 2 DMA channels. but the  RS232 connection to connect the 2 ports is on the baseboard but I don't have one. I am just using wires on a breadboard to hook up UART0 TX to UART1 RX and the UART1 TX to the UART0 RX. I am notified that I received the 16 byte FIFO buffer from UART1 but when UART0 transmits to UART1, I am not getting the flag set saying I received the characters on the other DMA channel. I am wondering if something is not being initialized correctly

Comment: thanks, I am new to posting comments here. I will do that from now on